# Twilio Application Error making Calls

Tags: ios, twilio, application-error

Trying to make call from my app to a number using Twilio API's 
When call is received, getting application error 
and here is the debugger logs for that call:

> Error - 11200 HTTP retrieval failure 502 Bad Gateway errors

Passing a URL when POST Request.

Can anybody help me through this?

Comment: Hi, can you post some of your code in the question?

Comment: I am passing following parameters in my POST Request 

Call Url https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Calls.json
params
From = “My Twilio Phone number”,
To = “+91XXXXXXXXXX”
Url = “myserveraddres.com/data.xml”

and Basic Auth (AUTH_TOKEN and ACCOUNT_SID)

Comment: And what is in "data.xml"?

Comment: <Response>
<Say>
some Greeting </Say>
<Play>http://myserveraddress.com/bell.mp3</Play>
</Response>

Do i need to replace it ???  by 
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Number>+91XXXXXXXX/Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>

Comment: When call is received i hear "some greeting" and then a ring is played , voice is not transferred from my App to Phone number i called

Answer (score 0):

have you taken a look at [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11200) information from Twilio? They give possible causes and possible solutions for the error you received. Did you specify the correct [content-type](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/12300) header in your response?

If you could share your code, that would be great!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanx @Thev  Voice Request Url was nor returning any response.Now url returns <Response>
<Say>
Some Greetings
</Say>
<Play>http://myserveraddress.com/bell.mp3</Play>
</Response>
But now the issue is voice is not transferred.

Comment: @davy Hi, I am replying here because I don't have enough rep. I believe you do need to use <Dial> to connect to a phone number. <Play> and <Say> are only used to play a file or text-to-speech.